# I have created a parametric Optic Plan over a view using JavaScript in MarkLogic. How can I pass a parameter to the plan while invoking it?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9, marklogic-optic-api

Here is the plan I have created which can accept a parameter emplId to filter the results of the view:

```
declareUpdate();
const op = require('/MarkLogic/optic');

const EmployeePlanSQL = op.fromView('employees', 'EmployeeRecordsView',"")
     .select(['employeeId', 'employeeName', 'pnone'])
     .where(op.eq(op.col('employeeId'), op.param('emplId')))
     .orderBy('employeeId');;
const planObj = EmployeePlanSQL.export();

xdmp.documentInsert("emplRatePlanSQL.json", planObj);
```

Here is how I invoke it using JavaScript :

```
op.import(cts.doc('emplRatePlanSQL.json').toObject())
  .result();
```

How to pass the parameter emplId while invoking this plan?

Answer (score 2):

The optional second argument of the result() method specifies parameter bindings as in:

```
.result('object', {emplId: 1});
```

For more information, see:

http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_35758

and

http://docs.marklogic.com/AccessPlan.prototype.result

Hoping that helps,

Answer (score 1):

When parameterizing query plans, specify the parameter values in the second argument to `.result()`:

```
.result(null, { emplId: 1234 });
```

There is [an example in the Optic API guide](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/app-dev/OpticAPI#id_35758).